# Different Subject for different signers

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to give the email subject differently for different signers in Docusign using REST API call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to questions from others. And please check/accept the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify an email subject and body for each signer.

See the `emailNotification` field of the `signer` object.

See the Definitions section of the [Envelopes: create method](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/).